# How do I open deja-dup during a current backup?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I've got deja-dup doing regular backups and today it began one in the background. This will take a few hours and I want to pause it.

Unfortunately, when I try to do so, the usual backup window that has the pause button is nowhere to be found. Is there a way to get that window open so I can pause the backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first install xdotool if you didn't do yet.

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Now specify the PID of the `deja-dup` backup process.

```
ps aux | grep deja
user  32052 18.5  0.1 1166992 33240 ?       Sl   13:31   0:00 gnome-control-center deja-dup
user  32073 11.5  0.0 744364 19704 ?        SNl  13:31   0:00 deja-dup --backup
user  32100  0.0  0.0   9452   944 pts/2    S+   13:31   0:00 grep --color=auto deja
```

save the PID  of the --backup process which is `32073` for this example

Now use the `xdotool`

```
xdotool windowactivate `xdotool search --pid PROCESS_PID | tail -1`
```

In this example means

```
xdotool windowactivate `xdotool search --pid 32073 | tail -1`
```

and this will bring back the deja-dup backup window so you can do what you want.

Comment: @awesomebing1 you are welcome

Comment: "XGetWindowProperty[_NET_WM_DESKTOP] failed (code=1)"
 here

Comment: I get the feeling this will only work if the window is hidden