# How can I check if a deja-dup/duplicity backup is in progress and pause/stop it?

Tags: backup, deja-dup, duplicity

I have scheduled duplicity backups via deja-dup on my laptop. However, when I am on battery power I want to pause or stop the backup.

Comment: I found https://askubuntu.com/questions/528024/how-do-i-open-deja-dup-during-a-current-backup#615288 which is not working for me. Also, I would like a CLI solution.